# PHP function to keep only a-z 0-9 and replace spaces with "-" (including regular expression)

Tags: php, regex

I want to write a PHP function that keeps only a-z (keeps all letters as lowercase) 0-9 and "-", and replace spaces with "-".

Here is what I have so far:

```
      ...
      $s = strtolower($s);
      $s = str_replace(' ', '-', $s);
      $s = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9]\-/", "", $s);
```

But I noticed that it keeps "?" (question marks) and I'm hoping that it doesn't keep other characters that I haven't noticed.

How could I correct it to obtain the expected result?

(I'm not super comfortable with regular expressions, especially when switching languages/tools.)

Comment: Did you mean `[^a-z0-9-]`? `[^a-z0-9]\-` means one character which is not `a`..`z` and not `0`..`9`, and _then_ a hyphen _following_ that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = strtolower($s);
$s = str_replace(' ', '-', $s);
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\-]+/", "", $s);
```

1. You did not have the \- in the [] brackets.
   It also seems you can use - instead of \-, both worked for me.
2. You need to add multiplier of the searched characters.
   In this case, I used +.

The plus sign indicates one or more occurrences of the preceding element.